# How to void overlap of 2 images when drag and drop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to drag and drop images in a panel and want to avoid overlap of images.The images are dragging from another panel and I want to build a layout from that images. I was able to drag and drop images to the panel and want to avoid overlap when dropped.

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
           // this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;

```
        Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;
        if (c != null)
        {
            mycontrol = c;


              c.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient((new Point(e.X, e.Y)));

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(c);

        }  

    }
```

e.X and e.Y must not be lied on top of other controls in the panel.

How can I do that? Please give me a appropriate solution.

Thank you.

Comment: @C. Karunarathne - Stackoverflow users expect people to do at least a bit of work and show it. No one will respond to a request for code if you don't provide some and explain what is not working.

Comment: @C. Karunarathne, even if you have no idea how to start to code, you can provide more info. E.g. Where to drop the images? From file or from another Image control in a Winform? What are your specific requirements? E.g. If the dragged image is larger than the target panel, what is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 interpretations of your question:

1) That you want your dropped control to have it's Zorder adjusted, so that it is "behind" the rest of your controls in your panel...as presumably you want the dropped image to be the background?

If so, then just do:

c.SendToBack();

after you have done the this.panel1.Controls.Add(c);

or

2) That you are actually dropping several images into the panel, and you want them to be laid out as if they were in a list one after the other vertically.

If you want this, then you need to position the dropped image so that it's top and left coordinates are specified so that they begin from the "bottom-most" image control that appears in your panel.

You can work out the coordinate in several different ways depending on how you maintain the controls in the .Control collection.

If the controls that appear in the Controls collection are properly sorted/maintained in an order equating to their vertical Y offsets, then you can simply look at the last control in the .Controls collection, find its bottom y location:

e.g.

if (this.panel1.Controls.Count == 0)
{
    c.X = 0;
    c.Y = 0;
}
else
{
    c.X = 0;
    c.Y = this.panel1.Controls[this.panel1.Controls.Count - 1].Bottom;
}

If you don't maintain the image controls in pixel y order, then you would have to iterate over all the controls in the .Controls collection and find the one which had the biggest "bottom", and use that as the starting point for your newly dropped image control.